# Connect Laravel echo from Angular project

Tags: websocket, redis, socket.io, laravel-echo, angular-socket-io

I have a Laravel-echo-server with Redis running on my local. 
I created a test API endpoint, that emits broadcastable event.

on `http://localhost:8000/api/web-socket-test` I see the response in echo server CLI.[image]

I set-up laravel-echo  auth key and I can get the stat info from server API 
`http://localhost:6001/apps/APP_ID/status?auth_key=b73a61d0`.

[image]

The problem is with connecting to echo-server from Angular via ws: protocol. 
My connection code is

```
import {webSocket, WebSocketSubject} from 'rxjs/webSocket';
```

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  myWebSocket: WebSocketSubject<any> = webSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:6001');

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myWebSocket.subscribe(
      msg => console.log('message received: ' + msg),
      err => console.log(err),
      () => console.log('complete')
    );
  }
```

And finally I've got an error: **WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:6001/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response**.

[image]

How can I establish ws connection?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77571697/14344959

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to try connecting using the socket.io client libraries instead of using rxjs raw websockets.

Although it's not immediately clear from the laravel echo server docs, the project title states it's a 'Socket.io server for Laravel Echo'.  So I'm assuming you should use the socket.io client libraries for connections.

Comment: But what url and protocol should I use? Is this correct way to connect `ws://127.0.0.1:6001`.

Comment: In the laravel-echo docs it appears you don't need to specify this, only host and port.   You need to pass in a client instance of io (socket.io client) and then make sure to specify the 'broadcaster' option with value 'socket.io' too.  See the laravel-echo socketio-connector.ts source code for more details in here: https://github.com/laravel/echo

Comment: @jon hey laravel echo doesn't works for me in Angular. can you share your working sample code of angular? `this.echo = new Echo({
      broadcaster: 'socket.io',
      client: io,
      host: 'http://localhost:6001', // Change this to your Laravel Echo server host
    });
this.echo.connector.socket.on('connect', () => {             console.log('CONNECTED');         });` I'm can't getting this log. and can't see websocket request in broswer network section. what's wrong?

Comment: maybe it's authorization?  here's a snippet 

 `this.echo = new Echo({
          auth: { headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.authToken } },
          client: io,
          host: this.host,
          broadcaster: 'socket.io',
          key: this.echoServerAuthKey,
        });`