# Angular 7 and laravel-echo

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, socket.io, laravel-echo

So I'm trying to make backend laravel and frontend Angular to work.
Laravel version 5.8 and Angular 7.2
I have my event

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new Channel('test');
}

public function broadcastAs() {
    return 'message.sent';
}
```

I made a route to call it

```
Route::get('/fire', function () {
    event(new \App\Events\Messages\MessageEvent());
    return 'ok';
});
```

And in redis and laravel-echo-server it registers events

```
"PUBLISH" "test" "{\"event\":\"message.sent\",\"data\":{\"a\":\"a\",\"socket\":null},\"socket\":null}"
```

```
Channel: test
Event: message.sent
```

But whenever i try to connect to socket from angular something fails, and it does not connect nor throws error. Response form socket is `200` and it gets `200` every 25 seconds (echo sever config) but ws connection is not established and no events are caught

angular side

```
import {Component, Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id.toString(),
    templateUrl: 'index.html',
})

@Injectable()
export class MessagesPagesViewComponent {

    echo: any;

    constructor() {

        const SocketIoClient = require('socket.io-client');
        try {
            this.echo = new Echo({
                broadcaster: 'socket.io',
                host: 'localhost:6001',
                client: SocketIoClient,
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
        this.echo.connector.socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('CONNECTED');
        });

        this.echo.connector.socket.on('reconnecting', () => {
            console.log('CONNECTING');
        });

        this.echo.connector.socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log('DISCONNECTED');
        });

        this.echo.connector.socket.on('test.message.sent', (data) => {
           console.log('1', data);
        });

        this.echo.connector.socket.on('.message.sent', (data) => {
            console.log('2', data);
        });

        this.echo.connector.socket.on('message.sent', (data) => {
            console.log('3', data);
        });

        this.echo.join('test').joining((data) => {
            console.log('joining', data);
        }).leaving((data) => {
            console.log('leaving', data);
        });

        this.echo.join('test2').joining((data) => {
            console.log('joining', data);
        }).leaving((data) => {
            console.log('leaving', data);
        });

        this.echo.channel('test').listen('.message.sent', (data) => {
            console.log('From laravel echo: ', data);
        });
        this.echo.channel('test2').listen('.message.sent', (data) => {
            console.log('From laravel echo: ', data);
        });



        console.log(this.echo);
    }

}
```

laravel-echo-server.json

```
{
    "authHost": "http://localhost",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {
            "host": "172.24.0.2",
            "port": "6379"
        },
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "secureOptions": 67108864,
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": true,
        "allowOrigin": "*",
        "allowMethods": "GET, POST",
        "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your queue:worker running?

Comment: I got it working. My queue service was sync and it wasn't the problem. All I had to do was change line in `BroadcastServiceProvider` to `Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => 'auth.user:api']);` and of course add a Authorizaton header in my frontend connection.

Comment: hey laravel echo doesn't works for me in Angular. can you share your working sample code of angular? `this.echo.connector.socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('CONNECTED');
        });` I'm can't getting this log. and can't see websocket request in broswer network section. what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was face same issue. but I solved it.

Currently Laravel Echo is not establish websocket connect with socket.io-client v.4.7. but It works fine with socket.io-client version **`^2.5.0`**

> package.json

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "laravel-echo": "^1.15.3", // latest version as of 29th Nov, 2023
    "socket.io-client": "^2.5.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^3.0.0",
  }
}
```

[image: socket.io-client npm version list]

> notification.service.ts

```
// notification.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
// import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class NotificationService {
    private echo!: Echo;

    constructor() {
        this.initEcho();
    }

    private initEcho() {
        const io = require('socket.io-client');
        this.echo = new Echo({
            broadcaster: 'socket.io',
            client: io,
            host: 'http://localhost:6001', // Change this to your Laravel Echo server host
        });

        this.echo.connector.socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('%c Connected to WebSocket', 'background: blue; color: white');
        });

        this.echo.connector.socket.on('reconnecting', () => {
            console.log('%c ReConnecting to WebSocket', 'background: yellow; color: green');
        });

        this.echo.connector.socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log('%c Disconnected from WebSocket', 'background: red; color: white');
        });

        this.echo.channel('user-channel').listen('.UserEvent', (data: any) => {
            // Handle the real-time notification data here
            console.log('Notification received:', data);
        });
    }
}
```

> test-notification.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NotificationService } from './notification.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-notification',
  templateUrl: './test-notification.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-notification.component.scss']
})
export class TestNotificationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(protected notificationService: NotificationService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```